# Jump on crawled url with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

I would like to create a bot who is able to jump between url's crawler on each website.
[image]

If on the website 1 there is two url's, i would like to start 2 new instance for crawl there websites.

Maybe limit the number of instance at the same time.

My code actually work for only 1 website, it not able to jump on the getting url's.

```
from scrapy.contrib.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from scrapy.item import Item
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy import log

class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "crawler"
    allowed_domains = ["*"]
    start_urls = ["http://domainA.com"]
    rules = [Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True)]
    def parse_item(self,response):
        self.log('A response from %s just arrived!' % response.url)
```

Comment: Could you provide a real world reproduceable example noting what is your desired output is? Thanks.

Comment: You can use a work pool (in this case you can use a Queue). So you have one process responsible for creating jobs (URL to be crawled) and inserts it into the queue. Then you can use a number of threads to get work from the pool since the Queue is shared between them.

Comment: @alecxe Put in database expired domains.

Comment: @HugoSousa Do you have any exemple of scrapy project able to do that ? with rabbitmq or redis ?

Comment: Well you got zillions ways to do that. Here is a good reading on threads: http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/aix/library/au-threadingpython/

Answer (score 0):

You could define a parameter that becomes the starting url if it's passed and spawn new process with subprocess (https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) for each link that you get.

Maybe something like this:
(N.B - not tested)

```
class ExampleSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = "test_crawler"
    allowed_domains = ["*"]
    rules=[Rule(SgmlLinkExtractor(),callback='parse_item',follow=True)]

    def __init__(self, starting_url=None):

        if starting_url:
            self.start_urls = [starting_url]
        else:
            self.start_urls = ["http://www.domainA.com"]

        CrawlSpider.__init__(self)


    def parse_item(self,response):
        subprocess.call('scrapy crawl {0} -a starting_url    {1}'.format(self.name, response.url).split())
```